# Values not retained after postback during a method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, variables

I am currently working on migration of a vb.net desktop application into a web application, in the desktop application the previous developer had declared all the variables once on the

## form_load

```
stdate = VB6.Format(Now, "mmddyyyyhh")
current_month = CInt(Mid(stdate, 1, 2))
current_day = CInt(Mid(stdate, 3, 2))
current_year = CInt(Mid(stdate, 5, 4))
current_hour = CInt(Mid(stdate, 9, 2))
base_year = current_year
this_year = current_year
base_month = current_month
this_month = current_month
txtBaseyear.Text = CStr(base_year)
txtBaseMonth.Text = CStr(base_month)
swyearerror = 0
```

They were then able to use these variables anywhere in the code and it would retain the values.

## my application

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string format = "MMdyyyyhh";
    string stdate = now.ToString(format);
    Session["stdate"] = stdate;
    int current_month = Convert.ToInt32(now.Month);
    Session["currentmonth"] = current_month;
    int current_day = Convert.ToInt32(now.Day);
    Session["currentday"] = current_day;
    int current_year = Convert.ToInt32(now.Year);
    Session["currentyear"] = current_year;
    int current_hour = Convert.ToInt32(now.Hour);
    Session["currenthour"] = current_hour;
    int base_year = (int)(Session["currentyear"]);
    int this_year = (int)(Session["currentyear"]);
    int base_month = (int)(Session["currentmonth"]);
    int this_month = (int)(Session["currentmonth"]);
    TxtBase.Text = Convert.ToString(base_year);
    TxtBase1.Text = Convert.ToString(base_month);
}
```

Now each time there is a post-back when the text is changed the values are lost and set to zero so I tried storing it in a session but that still doesn't work.

Let me give you a visual of my situation.

1) on the first load everything loads fine.
2) then the users enters an item and hits enter

```
protected void TxtItem_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Calc_Rotation();
     Calc_Best_Before();
}
```

now...

```
public void Calc_Rotation()
{

    switch (current_month) becomes 0 suppose to be 4 
    {
        case 1:
            rotation_month = "A";
            break;
        case 2:
            rotation_month = "B";
            break;
        case 3:
            rotation_month = "G";
            break;
        case 4:
            rotation_month = "J";
            break;
        case 5:
            rotation_month = "K";
            break;
        case 6:
            rotation_month = "L";
            break;
        case 7:
            rotation_month = "N";
            break;
        case 8:
            rotation_month = "P";
            break;
        case 9:
            rotation_month = "S";
            break;
        case 10:
            rotation_month = "W";
            break;
        case 11:
            rotation_month = "Y";
            break;
        case 12:
            rotation_month = "Z";
            break;
    }

    switch (current_hour)  becomes 0 suppose to be the current hour
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            rotation_batch = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            rotation_batch = 4;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
            rotation_batch = 6;
            break;
        case 6:
        case 7:
            rotation_batch = 8;
            break;
        case 8:
        case 9:
            rotation_batch = 10;
            break;
        case 10:
        case 11:
            rotation_batch = 12;
            break;
        case 12:
        case 13:
            rotation_batch = 14;
            break;
        case 14:
        case 15:
            rotation_batch = 16;
            break;
        case 16:
        case 17:
            rotation_batch = 18;
            break;
        case 18:
        case 19:
            rotation_batch = 20;
            break;
        case 20:
        case 21:
            rotation_batch = 22;
            break;
        case 22:
        case 23:
            rotation_batch = 24;
            break;
    }
}
```

same goes for the Calc_Best_Before

after I tried the postback solution I am still getting 0 values.

[image]

Comment: web apps don't work like client apps - they are stateless.

Comment: HTTP is stateless.  When a server finishes serving a request the resources used to do so are cleaned up.  It looks like you need to read your Session to get the variables after postback.  Or, better yet, use JavaScript.

Comment: @ScoobyDrew18 how would javascript work better?

Comment: @codeman What you need to do is to pass the values in via a form, and then query for the posted values ... See for example this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466646/how-to-use-request-form-in-inherited-web-form

Comment: @jcolebrand It's a bit ambiguous what the desired outcome is, but it seems to be that he's trying to make changes on the client when the textbox value changes.  Wouldn't JavaScript be better than causing a postback each time the user changes the value?

Comment: @ScoobyDrew18 not necessarily. Sometimes there is a legitimate need to do the processing on the server. Sure this _particular_ example seems contrived, but baby steps...

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `Session` to store the values, you need to ensure that you are checking the `IsPostBack` Property. Otherwise, everytime the page postback occurs, you are initializing the values again and thus you loose the state.

`Page.IsPostBack` property basically signifies whether the Page is accessing the server for the first time or not.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (!IsPostBack)
             {

                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                string format = "MMdyyyyhh";
                string stdate = now.ToString(format);
                Session["stdate"] = stdate;
                int current_month = Convert.ToInt32(now.Month);
                Session["currentmonth"] = current_month;
                int current_day = Convert.ToInt32(now.Day);
                Session["currentday"] = current_day;
                int current_year = Convert.ToInt32(now.Year);
                Session["currentyear"] = current_year;
                int current_hour = Convert.ToInt32(now.Hour);
                Session["currenthour"] = current_hour;
                int base_year = (int)(Session["currentyear"]);
                int this_year = (int)(Session["currentyear"]);
                int base_month = (int)(Session["currentmonth"]);
                int this_month = (int)(Session["currentmonth"]);
                TxtBase.Text = Convert.ToString(base_year);
                TxtBase1.Text = Convert.ToString(base_month);
           }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

@CodeMan: You need to use the `Session` to read the value for the current month in the function `Calc_Rotation`. You are trying to read the value from the variable `current_month` which is an `int` and would default to zero.

**I would suggest you to use a Property to wrap up the `Session` Variable and then use the property in the code**. Below, i have created a wrapper property `CurrentMonth` which encapsulates the Read and write operations on `Session` in the webpage, declared at class scope. Simmilary you can create wrapper properties for other variables as well. After creating the properties, you need to read the property value in the `Calc_Rotation` function.

```
private int CurrentMonth {
            get {
                var monthfromSession = HttpContext.Current.Session["ClassNameSpace.CurrentMonth"];
                return monthfromSession!= null ? (int)monthfromSession : 0;
            }
                set {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["ClassNameSpace.CurrentMonth"] = value;
             }
        }



public void Calc_Rotation()
{

    switch (this.CurrentMonth)  // it should have correct month value now.
    {
        case 1:
            rotation_month = "A";
            break;
        case 2:
            rotation_month = "B";
            break;
        case 3:
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants the values from the form, not necessarily from the session. Just doesn't understand the differences of how to store values.

Comment: @Agalo That didn't work for me, I tried you solution but still it is getting set to zero.

Comment: @CodeMan which variable is set to Zero ? where are you reading the session ?

Comment: @CodeMan, i have updated the answer, it should work now.

Comment: @Agalo thanks for help, I tried the wrapper class  even that is returning a value 0 for this.CurrentMonth. do you know why??

Comment: @CodeMan, where are you setting the value, can you post your updated code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
       return;
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string format = "MMdyyyyhh";
    string stdate = now.ToString(format);
    Session["stdate"] = stdate;
    int current_month = Convert.ToInt32(now.Month);
    Session["currentmonth"] = current_month;
    int current_day = Convert.ToInt32(now.Day);
    Session["currentday"] = current_day;
    int current_year = Convert.ToInt32(now.Year);
    Session["currentyear"] = current_year;
    int current_hour = Convert.ToInt32(now.Hour);
    Session["currenthour"] = current_hour;
    int base_year = (int)(Session["currentyear"]);
    int this_year = (int)(Session["currentyear"]);
    int base_month = (int)(Session["currentmonth"]);
    int this_month = (int)(Session["currentmonth"]);
    TxtBase.Text = Convert.ToString(base_year);
    TxtBase1.Text = Convert.ToString(base_month);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside the below code. If the web page loads for the first time IsPostBack property is 'false' and code inside the if condition will be executed.
if the page loads after a post back IsPostBack turns to 'true' which cause program execution to escape the if condition.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{

}
```